# Android InstantApp and sharedUserId

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, dynamic-feature-module

I would like to create an **instant app** for one *application currently on the play store*.

For that, I made dynamic feature modules with all necessary things for instant experience.

The major problem is that the field `android:sharedUserId` is defined on main module.

When testing my work, we get the following error on logcat :

> android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: /data/app/vmdl143761699.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #2): sharedUserId not allowed in ephemeral application

This means that an instant app cannot work with sharedUserId field...

When I remove this field, my instant app works very well, but I cannot install main application or update previous installation version, I obtain this error :

> E/Finsky: [2] zdp.onReceive(15): Error -505 while installing xx.xx.xxx.xxx: INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE: Package xx.xxx.xxxx.xxx tried to change user null

Ok, Google specify that is not possible to delete this field without application reinstal... (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid)

So I could not have an instant app as long as I have sharedUserId field and I cannot delete it...

Is there any solution for my problem ?